# Complex Numbers - Omega

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm told that $ω^n$ = $ω^{(n+3k)}$

Also

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/be3a267674e45e39a7004dda3427844b.png?1366376465))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/b0c99b7f5e54905a030c8519995ecb1b.png?1366376533))</sub>

and $k = 0,1,2.$

How does $ω^{(-1)} = ω^{(2)}$, in this equation?

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e5c8dd47e3175d24ec19b2fc303b9dcf.png?1366376699))</sub>

Taking $ω^{(-k)}$, $k = 1$

$= ω^{(n + 3(-1))}  
= ω^{(n -3)}$

Also what does $n$ equal to?

I also have this information:

More generally, $ω^n = ω^{(n + 3k)}$ for all integers n and k.  Now $-1 = 2 + 3 * (-1)$, so
$ω^{-1} = ω^2$.

Where did the $2$ come from?

Btw can someone please edit this, cause I don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: Here your $\omega=\zeta_3=e^{2\pi i/3}$, which is a cube root of unity, so $\omega^3=\omega\cdot\omega^2=1$, so $\omega^2$ is the inverse $\omega^{-1}$. Is that what your concern is?

Comment: Yeah but how does the inversing work?

Comment: Well the inverse of $\omega$ is defined to be the element such that $\omega\cdot\omega^{-1}=1$. Since $\omega$ satisfies $\omega^3=1$, $\omega\cdot\omega^2=1$. Surely then $\omega^2$ satisfies what it means to be the inverse of $\omega$?

Comment: Okay I get that now. But would I do it for another number apart for $-1$

Comment: You can do it for any number that is congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$. As you've already mentioned $\omega^n=\omega^{n+3k}$, so $\omega^{-1}=\omega^2=\omega^5=\omega^8=\cdots$ etc. As long as the power can be written as $3k-1$ for some integer $k$, then it will always be the inverse of $\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\omega^{n+3k}=\omega^n\cdot(\omega^3)^k$.

Comment: Is this method not more complicated that the formula I was given?

Comment: @AdegokeA:  not if you realize that $\omega^3=1$

Comment: Oh I see. But about $n$?

Comment: @AdegokeA  if  $n=3u+v$ , $0\le v<3$  then $\omega^n=\omega^v$